# ionic html input field of type number

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Even though defining an input field as number still return as a string in the component

```
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="salary" 
      (ngModelChange)="calc($event)"
       required
      type="number" 
      name="salary">
</ion-input>
```

In the component as well the field is defined as a number

```
private salary: number;
```

Why does not it return as a number?

Thanks

Comment: as far as my knowledge it should be number. but can u make plnkr example?

Comment: What do you have in this calc() function?

Comment: @GabrielBarreto For now I am just console.log

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7121).

As a workaround, you can use the `ionChange` event on the input to transform the value to a number, and then assign it to a class variable.

In your template

```html
<ion-input [ngModel]="salary"
      (ionChange)="transform($event)"
      required
      type="number" 
      name="salary">
</ion-input>
```

In your component

```js
transform(event) {
  // Multiply by 1 to transform to number
  this.salary = event.value * 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Work Around:

```
private salary: number;
```

Instead Of type number specify it as , **string**:

```
private salary: string;
```

Then let **ion-input** return **string**

cast it it **integer** or **float** according to your requirements like this:

```
parseInt(salary)
```

if you cross check using **typeOf** it will give **number**.